# How can I add the username of a logged in wordpress user (sales person) who placed an order for a customer

Tags: email, woocommerce, orders

Our sales people use our website to place orders on customers behalf. I'd like the sales people's wordpress usernames to appear in woo-commerce admin order emails.

Answer (score 0):

Add bellow code goes in `functions.php` file of your active child theme (or active theme) or also in any plugin file. It will add an extra column with :created by and Modified by .

[image]

```
//for order columns add who made this
add_filter( 'manage_edit-shop_order_columns', 'firefog_post_type_columns', 20 );

function firefog_heirch_columns( $column, $post_id ) {
    switch ( $column ) {
    case 'modified':
        $m_orig     = get_post_field( 'post_modified', $post_id, 'raw' );
        $m_stamp    = strtotime( $m_orig );
        $modified   = date('d/m/y @ g:i a', $m_stamp );
            $modr_id      = get_post_meta( $post_id, '_edit_last', true );
            $auth_id      = get_post_field( 'post_author', $post_id, 'raw' );
            $user_id      = !empty( $modr_id ) ? $modr_id : $auth_id;
            $user_info    = get_userdata( $user_id );

            $user_nicename=$user_info->user_nicename;


            echo '<p class="mod-date">';
            echo '<em>on'.$modified.'</em><br />';
            echo 'by <strong>'.$user_info->display_name.'<strong> ('.$user_id.')';
            echo '</p>';
        break;
    // end all case breaks
    }
}

function firefog_post_type_columns( $columns ) {
    $columns['modified']    = 'Last Modified';
    $columns['author']      = 'Created By';
    return $columns;
}
```

You Can Manage Column from Screen Options like bellow image
[image]

Comment: Thanks. Columns where added successfully but the data is not filled.